# Can I recover my lawn from fertilizer burn?

Tags: grass, fertilizer, lawn-repair

I was hoping to improve my lawn.

I used Scott's Weed & Feed with a little GrubX in hopes of killing weeds and  improving the look of my lawn.  (Fig A)
[image]

I didn't think I over did it, but obviously I burnt my lawn in these long strips.

(Fig B)
[image]

Can I recover from this (this season)?  If so, how?

Comment: How long ago did you apply the chemicals? Watering/rain and time will often be all that is necessary to get grass to recover from non-lethal over fertilization.

Comment: Last Monday, July 1st

Comment: I would think it would take longer to recover than that. If the area isn't already totally saturated, you could water a bit more to keep the nitrogen leaching from the area. One thing to note is that this generally doesn't happen with organic fertilizers which typically only release their nitrogen as bacteria break them down. The synthetic fertilizers are highly soluble and will burn if applied too heavily.

Comment: It was "Scott's Weed & Feed"  Would you consider that synthetic?

Comment: I have used Milorganite.  With Milorganite  I noticed if my drop spreader "dropped" too much it killed the grass in that area (yet the grass surrounding the spill GROWS)

Comment: I should have been more clear. When I think of organic fertilizers I typically think of products with little soluble nitrogen. With these products the nitrogen isn't released (made soluble for plants to use) until bacteria start breaking it down. Manures (chicken, horse, Milorganite, etc) can have much higher amounts of soluble nitrogen (you may hear them described as being "hot") which can burn and/or leach into the ground. This can also happen with unfinished compost.